# How to Connect to SQL Server using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Sure this is a really dumb question, but how do I connect my C# console app to a SQL Server Instance?

Have done this plenty of times with c# Web Apps, but this is the first console app I've done.

The only data source I can see (in VS 2010) is SQL Server Database File - I can't see how to connect to a SQL instance on a different server.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Step 1: Add a connection to your Server Explorer**

[image]

After that is added, you should see it appear under the server exlporer tab on the left side of your screen.

**Step 2: Add a Linq to SQL file (.dbml) to your project**

[image]

**Step 3: Open the .dbml file from the file explorer on the right hand side of Visual Studio**

**Step 4: Open up your connection via the drop down arrows on you server browser so that you can see the tables you which to use in your console app**

**Step 5: Drag them onto the design area (as seen by the yellow lines and the result of doing this in the green box)**

[image]

**Step 6: Go back to your .cs page for your console, instantiate, and get to work**

[image]

EDIT:

My guess would be that you may be missing SQL server from your computer. Check your start menu, do you have Microsoft SQL Server folder with a configuration tool in it as seen here?:

[image]

Comment: Cheers. It's step 1 that's causing a problem though. The only option I have under Data Source is: "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)" and the Change button is grayed out. Have I missed a step to enable "MS SQL Server (SqlClient)"?

Comment: Yep - got SQL Server 2008 tools installed. Weird thing is I also have Visual Studio Web Developer Express, and it works fine from here.

Comment: That is very odd. That would indicate that Visual Studio is the culprit. I searched around and didn't see anyone else with the exact same problem, so a quick reinstall, or (repair if it has that option) may help, but I'm never one to recommend that as the first step as its long and tedious.

Comment: Yeah - I'm starting to think that's the best bet. :-(

Comment: Just checked and repair is in option under control panel, good luck :)!

Comment: Step 6 DataClass1DataContext "The type or namespace name could not be found" After adding the dbml I compiled successfully and tried again but problem persists.

Comment: @KreepN: I done this steps but `mydataclassDataContex` object don't known in my console application project.why?

Comment: @sarina Might need to be more specific. Is the .Dbml file in the same project? If it is in a folder or some sub-directory, make sure you have a reference to that namespace in your code where you are trying to use the context.

Answer (score 1):

When you've created your console application, in the Solution Explorer, choose `Add New Item` and you should get a dialog box something like this:

[image]

What you're looking for is the **Linq-to-SQL Classes** which creates a `*.dbml` model file.

For a very complete and thorough introduction to Linq-to-SQL, read [Scott Guthrie's Using Linq to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) blog series (many posts). Those things all apply to any kind of app using Linq-to-SQL to talk to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a new LINQ To SQL dbml to your console app, and use Visual Studio's Server Explorer as part of the process.

Add a .dbml to your project as per normal.

Your Server Explorer window in Visual Studio should allow you to create a new Connection. Ensure you're using SqlClient. Here you can enter the instance name of your SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: The only option I have under Data Source is: "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)" and the Change button is grayed out. Have I missed a step to enable "MS SQL Server (SqlClient)"?