# Getting an error "This server version is not supported. Only servers up to microsoft sql server 2005" on linq to sql connection?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

For some days I am a little desperate about a problem in Visual Studio 2008, what happens is that in my company I work with VS 2008 and SQL Server 2014, It normally works well.

On choosing to work with linq to sql by following the step on connecting with my database [How to Connect to SQL Server using LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908428/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-linq-to-sql)

But on trying to connect with the database using server exlporer i got the error that

> This server version is not supported. Only servers up to microsoft sql
>   server 2005

I have faced the similar scenario with the datagridview when connecting the datagridview with sql server through the designer form. I overcame the issue through handling the connection in coding rather than using the design form.

So now my question is whether it is possible to do the same in linqtosql. I want to know whether there is a way to connect the dataclass.dbml to the sql server through coding rather than connecting with via server explorer in designer form.

is there any other way to solve the issue other than upgrading the vs?

Comment: Even though your Sql Server is 2014, is it set to compatibility mode for a pre 2005 version?

Comment: I think no the compatibiltiy_level is 110.

Comment: Did you know that development of linq to sql was stopped a decade ago? It's written in the [linq to sql tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-sql/info)

Comment: See https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/21/sql-server-2008-fix-connection-error-with-visual-studio-2008-server-version-is-not-supported/